# Can't use a y variable in aes_string

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, aesthetics

I am currently working with COVID-19 data from Peru and I want to use a Rmisc::multiplot to show the development of positive cases in each region of the country. So I am trying to code a loop to generate 25 plots. Only as a matter of example I am only using 4 variables:

```
     Fecha    Lima     La Libertad  Madre de Dios
1 2020-04-24   10           2             1
2 2020-04-25   15           4             3
3 2020-04-26   20           8             3
```

I generated a vector with the names of the regions:

```
nombre_regiones <- c("Lima", "La Libertad", "Madre de Dios")
```

And I created an empty list to store the 25 plots within:

```
regiones <- list()
```

Then I used this for loop to generate and store each plot in the list "regiones":

```
for (w in seq_along(nombre_regiones)) { 
  nombre <- paste("r", w, sep = "")
  assign(nombre, ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x = "Fecha", y = nombre_regiones[w])) + geom_line() + geom_point() + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d, %m", date_breaks  ="1 day") + geom_text(aes_string(label = nombre_regiones[w])))
  regiones[[w]] <- nombre
}
```

The loop created `r1` and stored the plot within but when `w = 2`, that means `nombre_regiones[w]` = `"La Libertad"` I got the next warning:

```
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:4: unexpected symbol
1: La Libertad
       ^
```

Because of that I can't create the second plot and the same thing happens with the third region `"Madre de Dios"`. I tried different things and look up for similar cases but I didn't have luck. Also `regiones[[w]] <- nombre` isn't working but that's something I'll look up later. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The dataframe with the variables "Fecha", "Lima", "La Libertad" and "Madre de Dios" is store with the object name "df".

Comment: Please check my solution below.  It is working with the changes.

Comment: @akruni got this in the console `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only` when I try to call r1, r2 or r3.

Comment: you probbaly need to run `df$Fecha <- as.Date(df$Fecha)` first.

Comment: @ErnestoRiverosBarrientos if you check my data, the `Fecha` is `Date` class.

Comment: The problem is I uses this `df$Fecha <- as.Date(df$Fecha, origin = "1899-12-30")` to prepare my data and when I erase the `origin` parameter I got `Error in as.Date.numeric(df$Fecha) : 
  'origin' must be supplied`. So I think the problem is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to initiate the `list` with full length

```
regiones <- vector('list', length(nombre_regiones))
```

Also, the `aes_string` is now deprecated.  Instead, can be converted to `sym`bol and evaluated (`!!`)

```
library(ggplot2)
for (w in seq_along(nombre_regiones)) { 
      nombre <- paste0("r", w)
      assign(nombre, ggplot(data = df,
          aes(x = Fecha, y = !! rlang::sym(nombre_regiones[w]))) +   
              geom_line() + 
              geom_point() + 
              scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d, %m", date_breaks  ="1 day") +
              geom_text(aes(label = !! rlang::sym(nombre_regiones[w]))))
      regiones[[w]] <- nombre
 }
```

-output r2

[image]

-output r3

[image]

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Fecha = structure(c(18376, 18377, 18378), class = "Date"), 
    Lima = c(10L, 15L, 20L), `La Libertad` = c(2L, 4L, 8L), `Madre de Dios` = c(1L, 
    3L, 3L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I forgot to change the `paste` function. It ran as I wanted, thank you very much.